# Joining 2 tables with where clause and order by counting the number of association

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 PostgreSQL tables, Articles and Votes. Each Article can have many Votes on any time. So the tables look like these:

Article:

```
ID, Title, Content
1, Title, Content
2, Title, Content
3, Title, Content
```

Votes:

```
ID, ArticleID, UserID, Created_at
1, 1, userA, 1489266747
2, 1, userB, 1489266757
3, 2, userC, 1489266767
```

Now I want to:

1. Select all the articles,
2. Order all the articles by the number of latest (within 24h) votes

Any suggestions how to do these? I think I need to use left join but still having trouble for selecting the latest votes.

Comment: common practice here is that you at least try to write a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can put the ordering criteria directly in `ORDER BY` using a subquery:

```
select a.*
from articles a
order by (select count(*)
          from votes v
          where v.ArticleId = a.id and
                v.CreatedAt >= extract(epoch from now()) - 24*60*60
         ) desc;
```

Personally, I would want to see the number of votes in the `SELECT`, but you are explicitly not asking for that information.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT ID, Title, Content,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Votes WHERE ArticleID = Article.OD AND Created_at >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) as votes_24h
FROM Article
ORDER BY votes_24h DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN, group by articles and order by `COUNT()`:

```
select a.ID, a.Title, a.Content
from Article a
left join Votes v
    on  v.ArticleID = a.ID
    and v.Created_at >= extract(epoch from now()) - 24*60*60
group by a.ID, a.Title, a.Content
order by count(v.ArticleID) desc, a.ID
```

Note that the 24h condition needs to be in the ON clause in order to show articles that had no votes in the last 24h.

You can also add the count to the SELECT clause and order by its alias:

```
select a.ID, a.Title, a.Content, count(v.ArticleID) as voteCount
from Article a
left join Votes v
    on  v.ArticleID = a.ID
    and v.Created_at >= extract(epoch from now()) - 24*60*60
group by a.ID, a.Title, a.Content
order by voteCount desc, a.ID;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/LGXXCS89847